# How can I use the captured group in the same regex

Tags: regex, android-studio, intellij-idea

```
mFoo = foo;
mBar = bar;
// convert to
this.foo = foo;
this.bar = bar;
```

How to use a regex to handle this substitution? Please help. Here is the method I used in Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) `Edit -> Find -> Replace in Path`

```
Text to find: m([A-Z])([A-Za-z0-9]+) = L$1$2
Replace with: this\.L$1$2 = L$1$2
```

**Update**

`L` above is a typo. It should be `\L` according to [JetBrains' document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html)

Comment: What language/tool? What have you tried? BTW, you can use back-reference.

Comment: I am using Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) `Edit -> Find -> Replace in Path`

Comment: Using backreferences. `\1, \2` etc.

Comment: You might wanna check if the flavor you are using  supports `\1` or `$1` for back referencing.

Comment: [**Find:** `m(\S+)` **Replace:** `this.m$1`](https://regex101.com/r/cL7eL2/2)

Comment: @noob Unfortunately, it seemed not working with the back referencing in the same regex, or maybe I use it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a pattern with back-reference and grouping the last words after "=":

Text to find:

> m([A-Z])([A-Za-z0-9]+) = (L\1\2)

Replace with:

> this.L$1$2 = $3

After your comments, I understand that you have also problems with lowercase/uppercase characters. So try this pattern (I have also simplified the regex):

```
m(\p{Alpha})(\w+) = (((?i)\1)\2)
```

and this replace string:

```
this\.L$1$2 = $3
```

So with your example with an input text:

```
mContext = context
```

you obtain this:

```
this.LContext = context
```

I don't know if "L" specified in your text/replace string is your typo error or other but if it's so you can change the "replace string" in the following way:

```
this\.$3 = $3
```

So you can obtain this:

```
this.context = context
```

Let me know if this help you!

Comment: I'll try the backreference feature on Android Studio and it works

Comment: `L\1` seemed not same as `L$1`, but back-reference `\1` worked. `L\1` cannot match lower case `\1`

Comment: Could you put a text example? So I'll check the mistake

Comment: `mContext = context;` I have checked case sensitive option.

Comment: Ok you have a problem with a lower case not with back-reference. I enriched the answer

Comment: `L` is a typo. It should be `\L` according to [jetbrains document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html) `m(\p{Alpha})(\w+) = (((?i)\1)\2)` and `this\.$3 = $3` works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried to use `\L` in **Replace with** text field of IntelliJ IDEA's **Replace in Path** dialog, but it shows some kind of syntax error. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Simona R., a simple example in Android Studio.

I want to replace

```
parentFragmentManager.let { dialogFragment.show(it, AlertDialogFragment.TAG) }
```

to

```
dialogFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, AlertDialogFragment.TAG)
```

in several classes so that two parameters may change.

Then I use replacement with `$1` and `$2`:

```
parentFragmentManager.let \{ (\w+).show\(it, (\w+).TAG\) \}
$1.show\(parentFragmentManager, $2.TAG\)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a text file with a list of statements:

```html
This is text one$
This is text two!
Is this text three?
```

And you want to escape all metacharacter.
1. In Android studio open the "Find and Replace" feature by hitting ctrl+R
2. In the "find" field enter:
**([[\\^\$.\|\?*+(){}])**
3. Check the checkbox for "Regex"
4. In the "replace" field enter:
**\$1**

The result should now look like this:

```
This is text one\$
This is text two\!
Is this text three\?
```