# Replace data after .PNG extension in image tag regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is my code

```
<img src="folder/img1.jpg?somestring">
<img src="folder/img2.jpg?somediffstring">
```

want to replace somestring & somediffstring with another string in whole html. please suggest some regular expression with php.

example
 change to  using regular expression or anything

Comment: Can you provide some sample example?

Comment: You could consider using use a parser to get the images and replace the src

Comment: Please suggest some code or name

Comment: Please check my updated Answer @Coder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [you shouldn't parse HTML with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5955745).

---

#### Solution 1

Now, if you are exclusively parsing `img` tags, you could come up with a satisfying enough solution like this:

```
(\b\.jpg|\b\.png)\?(.*?)\"
```

That is:

```
(\b\.jpg|\b\.png)  # 1st Capturing Group
    \b\.jpg        # 1st Alternative: match ``.jpg`` literally
    \b\.png        # 2nd Alternative: match ``.png`` literally
\?                 # Match the character ? literally
(.+?)              # 2nd Capturing Group
    .+?            # Match any character between one and unlimited times,
                   # as few times as possible, expanding as needed.
\"                 # Match the character " literally
```

#### Problem

What's the problem? We are not checking if we are inside an `img` tag. This will match everywhere in the HTML.

---

#### Solution 2

Let's add the check for `img > src`:

```
<img.+?src=\".*?(\b\.jpg|\b\.png)\?(.+?)\"
```

That is:

```
<img       # Match ``<img`` literally
.+?        # Match any character between one and unlimited times,
           # as few times as possible, expanding as needed.
           # Needed in case there are rel or alt options inside the img tag.
src=\"     # Match ``src="`` literally
...        # The rest is same as before.
```

#### Problem

Does this really do its job? Apparently yes, but in reality no.

Consider the following HTML code

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG" />
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.jpg?)">
     blah blah
</div>
```

It shouldn't match right? But it does (if you remove line-breaks). The regular expression above starts the match at `<img src="`, and will stop at `">` of the `div` tag. The capturing group will contain the characters between `?` and `"`: `)`, substituting it will break the HTML.

This was just an example, but many other situations will match even if they should not.

---

#### Other solutions...?

No matter how many constraints you can add to your RegEx and how sophisticated it becomes... HTML is a **Context-Free Language** and it can't be captured by a Regular Expression, which only recognizes **Regular Languages**.

---

#### In PHP

Still sure you're gonna use Regular Expressions? Alright, then your `PHP` function is `preg_replace`. You only need to keep in mind that it will replace **everything that matched**, not only the capturing groups. Hence, you need to wrap what you want to *"remember"* into another capturing group:

```
$str = '<img src="folder/img1.jpg?foo">';
$pattern = '/(<img.+?src=\".*?(\b\.jpg|\b\.png)\?)(.+?)(\")/';
$replacement = '$1' . 'bar' . '$4';

$str_replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);

// Now you have $str_replaced = '<img src="folder/img1.jpg?bar">';
```

Comment: Hi, its not working with this string `<img src=\"https:\/\/storage.blob.core.windows.net\/org-x3-292\/image\/_5c237908e982b_1545828616.png?st=bJPMsZqeF4bRk90xDm%2FbzA%3D&sdev=2015-12-11\" class=\"c5390\"\/>`

Answer (score 1):

With reference to this [How can I use the captured group in the same regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973048/how-can-i-use-the-captured-group-in-the-same-regex/34973131#34973131)

suppose u wanna change `img1.jpg?somestring` to `img1.jpg?somestringAAA`
and `img2.jpg?somediffstring` to `img2.jpg?somediffstringAAA`

Search for: `src="([a-zA-Z.0-9_]*)[?]([a-zA-Z.0-9_]*)">`

Replace with: `src="$1?$2AAA">`

here $1 represents whatever is inside first round paranthesis () , i.e., img1.jpg
and $2 represents second paranthesis

**UPDATE:**

```
$string = 'img1.jpg?somestring';
$pattern = '/([a-zA-Z.0-9_]*)[?]([a-zA-Z.0-9_]*)/i';
$replacement = '$1?$2AAA';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: thanks... can you update this with simple php code actually i am fresher in PHP

Comment: Did you try it with: `<img src="folder/img1.jpg?somestring">`? That doesn't work. They want to replace **in** img tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way :

```html
<?php

$url_value = "folder/img2.jpg?somediffstring";

echo $url =substr($url_value, 0, strpos($url_value, "?"));




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex \?(\w*)"

if u want to replace somestring and somediffstring with xx then u can replace it with regex \?(\w*)" and value as ?xx

https://regex101.com/r/S5pPuW/1